# TinyMCE won't display properly in Fancybox on second view in IE8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox, tinymce

I'm using a fancybox to display a form with a tinyMCE inside it in a rails app. The first time I open the fancybox it works fine, but when I close it and reopen it, the initial value of the tinyMCE doesn't appear until I type a character into the tinyMCE.

Upon debugging, I found that the first time I close the fancybox, I get an error where 'window.parent.tinyMCE' is null or not an object, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Does anyone know how to make sure the tinyMCE shows the initial value on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in case anyone is having this issue -- in the afterShow callback, I added tinyMCE.get(editor_id).initContentBody();